# minimum weight shortest path for all pairs of vertices with exactly k blue edges

Tags: graph-algorithm

Basically a subset of the graph has edges which are blue

So I know how to find all pairs shortest paths with DP in O(n^3), but how do I account for color and the exactness of the number of edges required for the problem?

Comment: not sure but complexity of what you require might be higher than n^3 because of the constraint 'exactly k'

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in O(k^2 . n^3) using a variant of Floydd-Warshall.

Instead of keeping track of the minimum path weight *d(i,j)* between two nodes *i* and *j*, you keep track of the minimum path weight *d(i,j,r)* for paths between *i* and *j* with exactly *r* blue edges, for 0 ≤ *r* ≤ *k*.

The update step when examining paths through a node *m*, where normally *d(i,j)* would be updated with the sum of *d(i,m)* and *d(m,j)* if it is smaller, becomes:

```
for u: 0 .. k
    for v: 0 .. (k-u)
        s = d(i,m,u) + d(m,j,v)
        d(i,j,u+v) = min( s, d(i,j,u+v) )
```

At the end, you then read off *d(i,j,k)*.

Comment: Squinting at that, the update step does look a bit similar to a discrete convolution (min instead of sum, addition instead of multiplication). There might correspondingly be a fancy transformation of the vectors _(d(i,j,0),...,d(i,j,k))_ that allows the update to be done in O(_k_ log _k_) instead of O(_k_^2). I'll think more about this!

Comment: Okie. A bit of reading indicates that the update step is an example of '(min,+)-convolution' (or just 'min-convolution'), and the current best algorithm is O(k^2 / log k).